# Apache server doesn't start if try to load mod_wsgi

Tags: apache, mod-wsgi

I'm trying to move my project from the development server to an Apache server.

I run on a Windows 8.1 x64 machine and Python 2.7

I installed Apache 2.2.25 x86 and everything went fine, the server is active; then I downloaded the precompiled mod_wsgi-3.4.ap22.win32-py2.7 (the x86 version to match the version of Apache).

I moved the mod_wsgi.so into the modules folder of the Apache installation and added this line: `LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so` to the httpd config; then, when I try to restart the server it fails leaving this error log:

```
[Fri Jan 10 18:53:18 2014] [notice] Parent: Received restart signal -- Restarting the server.
[Fri Jan 10 18:53:18 2014] [notice] Child 9772: Exit event signaled. Child process is ending.
httpd.exe: Syntax error on line 130 of C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/modules/mod_wsgi.so into server: **Impossible to find the specified module**
[Fri Jan 10 18:53:18 2014] [warn] (OS 995)**I/O operation terminated because of the thread's exit or the application's request.**  : winnt_accept: Asynchronous AcceptEx failed.
[Fri Jan 10 18:53:19 2014] [notice] Child 9772: Released the start mutex
[Fri Jan 10 18:53:20 2014] [notice] Child 9772: All worker threads have exited.
[Fri Jan 10 18:53:20 2014] [notice] Child 9772: Child process is exiting
```

note: the bold (**) parts where in my native language and I simply translated them.

I made sure that the module was actually called `mod_wsgi.so` so I can't really see where's the problem.

**Edit:** found the problem. Python (and therfore MySQL pyton mod) were x64 and not x86. Installed the right versions of both and it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

The key seems to be this:

```
Cannot load C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/modules/mod_wsgi.so into server: **Impossible to find the specified module**
```

This seems pretty clear.  Either that file doesn't exist on your server, or if it does, Apache can't read it.  Is it readable by EVERYONE?